# FIX5.0 Reference Tag

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixn

I'm new to FIX protocol development. Our company needs to connect to a broker and they are using FIX5.0/FIXT.1.1

I want to know which specific tag i can add "reference" information in the tag and the FIX server, whatever it does (reject, execution report, acknowledge, whatever) it would resend the tag with the same information.

I am not talking about Tag=11 (ClOrdId) or Tag=41 (OrigClOrdID)
I know these return data back to me as well, but i need another tag that does similar.
So is there a tag like this, like a reference tag where if I send the text "Hello World",
it should send back to me "Hello World" always if it's from the same order.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for your counterparty.  The thing you want will exist only if they coded it in their system.

FIX is just a message-sending and receiving protocol.  While it has mandated behavior for admin messages (login, logout, heartbeat, etc), it does not mandate how application messages behave.  The default FIX dictionary is best thought of as a suggestion: in practice, every counterparty does their own things and has their own quirks.

(For what it's worth, I'm not aware of the default FIX dictionary providing a "echo" service like you want either.)

Answer (score 0):

Like Grant said it is dependent on your counter-party. Maybe they support `526/SecondaryClOrdID` if you don't want (for whatever reason) to use `11/ClOrdID`.

https://fiximate.fixtrading.org/en/FIX.Latest/tag526.html

Some counterparties also support this via the `58/Text` field.